# How to use an android app's source code (in Java) to make a cross-platform program with xamarin

Tags: java, xamarin

I have created an android app that I would like to port to iOS and the windows platform. I know that I can create this kind of a program using C# with Xamarin because I have experimented with that sort of thing before; however, I would prefer not to have to convert all the code to C# as that would be time-consuming and ultimately would just not be a good use of my time. From descriptions I have read in the Xamarin documentation, it seems to be doable, just I am not sure how. To clarify, I would like the Java code (the Android app source code) to be used by Xamarin to create identical apps, but on iOS and the universal windows platform. Thanks in advance.

Example of what I mean:
Generate an app that should do the exact same thing on all platforms from this java code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder uselessAlert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
uselessAlert.setMessage("Pointless Button v");
uselessAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}});
uselessAlert.create().show();
```

Of course, that is a very useless program that can easily be converted to C#, but I am dealing with a fairly complex one.

Comment: You can refactor your app to move the bulk of your code into an Android library, which can be re-used in Xamarin via a binding project.  Otherwise you would need to port your code to C#

Comment: @Jason I kind of understand what you are trying to say, but I don't know what you mean by refactor. From what I know, refactor is a kind of "smart rename", so I don't get why that would convert it into an Android library. Could you please be a bit more specific? I do get the part about using a binding library as I have used them before. Thanks for you help, I appreciate it!

Comment: refactor generally means to take working code and rearrange or make small fixes to it.  You might take a loop that works but is difficult to read and refactor it so that its more readable and therefore easier to maintain.  Or take a working app and break parts of it out into a separate library so you can reuse it in other apps, or create a binding library for it.

Comment: sorry, I misread your question - if you want to use your Andriod code in an iOS app, you will have to port it.  Binding libraries allow you to use native Android code in a Xamarin Android project, or native iOS code in a Xamarin iOS project, but not between Android and iOS

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't. Xamarin is a toolset that provides a C# and F# compiler for iOS and Android, as well as wrappers around the native iOS and Android SDKs. You can call into Java code by binding up a library, so you could call your existing Android Java library, but ONLY from an Android app, not from an iOS app as the APIs needed to run the Java code are specific to Android. In your code snippet above you reference AlertDialog. This is an Android API, and you can call this in C# from a Xamarin Android app, but there is no way to call this from an iOS or UWP app - the API simply doesn't exist. You would need to re-write this code for each platform.

The way Xamarin is cross-platform is because you can write your business logic - so everything that doesn't need to interact with the OS directly (i.e. not UI code) once, then reference this from an iOS, Android and UWP app.

What you would need to do first is to restructure your core business logic and re-write it in C# or F#. Then you would need to think about the UI and anything that interacts with the OS.

For your UI you then have two choices - write it using Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android and UWP (so use the native SDKs to build your apps), or use Xamarin.Forms which gives you an abstraction across the native APIs allowing you to write your UI once (the compromise being you get a lowest common denominator approach, and if you want to do fancy stuff you need to interact with the native APIs directly).

TL;DR - you can't just use Xamarin to magically port your Android app, you would need to re-write it.

Comment: Ok, so I only have to rewrite the logic for all the stuff the app does in the background and it will work on all the platforms, but the user interaction logic has to be platform-specific. Did I understand this correctly? Also, would it not just be possible to convert the app's logic into a .dll file and use it with c#, and can I not just use XAML to make one UI that is the same across all platforms? I am fairly certain there is a template for the XAML approach - I will look. Anyways, thanks for your answer; I really appreciate it.

Comment: Anything that doesn't call an API directly, or has an abstraction on it can be called from code that will run on all platforms (and there are a lot of abstractions such as using HttpClient for calling webservices from cross-platform code, Xamarin plugins for the camera etc.)
Not sure if you can convert Java code into a DLL that will run on all platforms - iOS doesn't ship with a Java runtime.
You can use XAML for a UI that is the same - this is Xamarin.Forms, so you write the UI once, but can't do everything. It does allow you to drop into native code to do everything though.